# Is a letter compare slower than number compare?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Bear with me here.

A couple months ago I remember my algorithms teacher discussing the implementation of bucket sort with us (named Distribution sort in my algorithms book) and how it works. Basically, instead of taking a number at face value, we start comparing by the binary representation like so:

```
// 32 bit integers.
Input:  9 4

4: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000110
9: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001001
// Etc.
```

and start comparing from right to left.

```
// First step.
4: 0
9: 1

Output: 9 4

// Second step
4: 1
9: 0

Output: 4 9 // Technically a stable algorithm, but we cannot observe that here.

// Third step

4: 1
9: 0

Output: 4 9

// Fourth step

4: 0
9: 1

Output: 9 4
```

And that's it; the other 28 iterations are all zeroes, so the output won't change anymore. Now, comparing a whole bunch of strings like this would go

```
// strings
Input: "Christian" "Denis"

Christian: C h r i s t i a n
Denis:     D e n i s

// First step.
Christian: n
Denis:     s

Output: Christian, Denis

// Second step
Christian: a
Denis:     i

Output: Denis, Christian

// ...
```

and so forth.

My question is, is comparing an signed char, a byte figure, faster than comparing ints?

If I had to assume, a 1 byte char is compared faster than a 4-byte integer. Is this correct? Can I make the same assumption with wchar_t, or UTF-16/32 formats?

Comment: That sounds more like radix sort than like bucket sort, and using radix 2 (base 2) is not a good idea.

Comment: I like how your instructor took a basic, constant time comparison and turned it into a linear one.  I must admit to never even having considered doing it that way.

Comment: Really? I haven't really seen the radix sort- my professor told us he wouldn't do that one with us because they're too similar. The first example is almost identical to the one he gave us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C or C++, a `char` is simply a one-byte integer (though "one byte" may or may not be 8 bits). That means that in a typical case, the only difference you have to deal with is whether a single-byte comparison is faster than a multi-byte comparison.

At least in most cases, the answer is no. Many RISC processors don't have instructions to deal with single bytes at all, so an operation on a single byte is carried out by sign-extending the byte to a word, operating on the word, and then (if necessary) masking all the bits outside of the single byte back to zeros -- i.e., operating on a whole word can often be around triple the speed of operating on a single byte.

Even on something like an x86 that supports single-byte operations directly, they're still often slower (on a modern processor). There are a couple of things that contribute to this. First of all, the instructions using registers of the size "natural" to the current mode have a simpler encoding than instructions using other sizes. Second, a fair number of x86 processors have what's called a "partial register stall" -- even though it's all implicit, internally they do something like the RISC does, carrying out an operation on a full-sized register, then merging it with the other bytes of the original value. For example, if you produce a result in AL then refer to EAX, the sequence will take longer to execute than if you produced the result in EAX to start with.

OTOH, if you look at old enough processors the reverse could be (and often was) true. For an extreme example, consider the Intel 8080 or Zilog Z80. Both had some 16-bit instructions, but the paths through the ALU were only 8 bits wide -- a 16-bit addition, for example, was actually carried out as two consecutive 8-bit additions. If you could get by with only an 8-bit operation, it was about twice as fast. Although 8-bit processors are a (distant) memory on desktop machines, they're still used in some embedded applications, so this isn't entirely obsolete either.

Answer (score 4):

One-byte chars are compared as numbers in C++. The exact speed depends on hosting CPU platform, and usually it's the same as speed of comparing 4-byte integers.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot assume anything about what type of comparison is faster, it depends on your particular platform.

Typically, `int` is the most "comfortable" size for the CPU, and so comparing these will usually be fastest.  Anything larger could well be slower, as it may need to be broken down into multiple `int`s.  Anything smaller *may* be as fast as an `int`, but depending on the memory architecture, mis-aligned reads may take longer.

On top of all this, there is the memory-bandwidth factor.  The larger the type, the higher the required bandwidth.  And then there's caching effects on top of that.  If the bottleneck is the CPU speed, then this doesn't matter.  Otherwise, it does.

Comment: Yes, in my experience, compilers and cpus optimize for integer operations. Integer values are usually aligned on doubleword/fullword/halfword boundaries depending on what size the  value is; bytes may or may not be word-aligned. Depending on your compiler and the underlying hardware architecture, the lack of word alignment may impose an access cost.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, is comparing an signed char, a byte figure, faster than comparing ints?

No. In C++, these operations will certainly be identical in speed. Modern CPUs do most operations on bytes in counts of 4 anyway<sup>1</sup> so the 1 byte vs. 4 bytes will not shave off any computation time.

> Please assume that conversion to binary with the integer example is irrelevant

There doesn’t happen any conversion. Numbers *are* represented as binary in the PC anyway.

---

<sup>1</sup> Gross simplification. But for the sake of argument we can state that an `int` in C++ will always be the “native” unit of measure on a given CPU.

Comment: What about the cost of reading `char`s from memory that aren't aligned to natural boundaries?

Comment: @Oli: not considered in my answer, and in principle a good point. However, no individual bytes are cached anyway so I’m not sure this ever plays a role. Now, if you had multi-byte values that crossed alignment borders … such as strings … but this should be (completely) offset by the length of the string.

Answer (score 1):

*If I had to assume, a 1 byte char is compared faster than a 4-byte integer. Is this correct?*

I very much doubt it.  If I where to guess my bet would be on the other way around if either is slower than the other.  Reason?  Most of today's processors are built to work directly with 4 byte types.

*Can I make the same assumption with wchar_t, or UTF-16/32 formats?*

No.  UTF formats are much more involved and cannot be compared directly, byte for byte, unless you're strictly checking for equality.

You really shouldn't be worrying about this kind of speed issue.  If your instructor is teaching you to be concerned about the speed of comparing a 1 byte type vs. a 4 byte type then you really need to take everything they say with a LOT of salt.  Write efficient algorithms, don't try optimizing at this level of detail.

Comment: Up to a point. Since SSE instructions came out, various people have used them for UTF-8 processing (primarily it lets you test whether 16 bytes of input are 16 codepoints of 7f or below in far fewer cycles than working with single bytes), giving up to 4 times the throughput for some cases. If your algorithms don't reflect the opportunities your hardware presents, then they have no relevance.

Answer (score 1):

As Al Kepp said, this depends on your platform. However, most CPUs have a built in instruction to compare [Words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computing%29), which, because of being a CPU instruction, always take the same time, as long as the data you are comparing fits in a single word.

[CMP x86 Assembly](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "alignment". Comparing chars, which are not aligned on natural word boundary will always be slower than comparing aligned data. Other than that, processor does multiple operations per cycle in pipeline and many other conditions have an effect on performance.